# Spring Oauth2 oauth/token POST method not mapped

Tags: java, spring, oauth

I've been trying to configure Oauth2 for Spring (4.0.1) with the most basic setup of the following security-context.xml

```
<oauth2:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" >
    <oauth2:authorization-code />
</oauth2:authorization-server>

<oauth2:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <oauth2:client 
            client-id="posConnector"           
            authorized-grant-types="password"
         />
</oauth2:client-details-service> 

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
</authentication-manager>
```

But the problem is when this is deployed the oauth/token POST does not get mapped, therefore giving me 405 Method not allowed error when trying to get the token.

```
2015-02-19 15:27:05,553 INFO  [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-7) Mapped "{[/oauth/confirm_access],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint.getAccessConfirmation(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception
2015-02-19 15:27:05,620 INFO  [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-7) Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.authorize(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)
2015-02-19 15:27:05,621 INFO  [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-7) Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize],methods=[POST],params=[user_oauth_approval],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.View org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.approveOrDeny(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)
2015-02-19 15:27:05,623 INFO  [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-7) Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2015-02-19 15:27:05,836 INFO  [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain] (MSC service thread 1-7) Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/api/v1/**'], [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@42ce8c43, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6f6e36dd, org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter@5f1fc920, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@27228f4f, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1138a37c, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@f7ea758, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2e09295e, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@1de29327]
```

I've solved the problem by adding a custom controller request mapping to a token endpoint and generating a token. But I'm still confused why the default basic configuration would not have that mapping.

Can anyone give me a clue about why this mapping is not happening?